# Android Firebase upload image

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I tried to upload images to Firebase storage by using the below code:

```
    FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    final StorageReference storageRef = firebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://xxx");

    Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File(url));
    mStorageRef = storageRef.child("images/"+file.getLastPathSegment());
    UploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(file);
    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle unsuccessful uploads
            Log.i(TAG, exception.toString());
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
            Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
        }
    });
```

However, I meet the below error:

`E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
                    An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
                     Code: -13000 HttpResult: 400
E/StorageException: The server has terminated the upload session
                    java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzabc(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzabb(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$8.run(Unknown Source)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)`

I found some people suggest updating the google play services on my phone. My phone has already have the latest version. I also tried enable anonymous sign in and make rules public.

Are there any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm such an idiot...

Should

`UploadTask uploadTask = mStorageRef.putFile(file);`

Instead of

`UploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(file);`

Comment: Good to hear that you found it. Btw: I usually name my folder references after the folder/file (e.g. `picturesReference` or `imageReference`) to reduce the chance of this happening.